# Magento Recommendations module and Snowplow schemas issue

Tags: magento2, adobe-sensei, product-recommendation

I have an issue with recommendations module statistics:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/product-recommendations.html

I installed Snowplow Debugger for Chrome to check if is it working and I noticed it is not working, unfortunately.
https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/verify.html

I got something like this in debugger:
[image]

So all schemas with "com.adobe.magento.entity" phrase are not valid in the debugger and when I try to open the URL e.g.:
http://iglucentral.com/schemas/com.adobe.magento.entity/magento-js-tracker/jsonschema/1-0-0
it says:

> Code: NoSuchKey Message: The specified key does not exist.

Other schemas are valid and I can open them URLs:
[image]

My recommendations statistics are empty but recommendations are working on the website.
The same issue on "normal" Magento frontend and Magento PWA.

Has anyone had a similar problem or can help with it?